# Why do I still get the old values for ManyToManyField comparison?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I found many ways to do it, but it seems that nothing work. I have a model that has a *manytomanyfield* to another model, I want to be able to compare old values from the manytomany field, and the new ones.

```
class A(models.Model):
    registers = models.ManyToManyField('B',blank=True)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        try:
            old_registers = self.__class__.objects.get(pk=self.pk).registers.all()
            print(old_registers)
            print(old_registers.difference(self.registers.values_list()))
        except A.DoesNotExist:
            old_registers = None

        if (old_registers != None) and old_registers.difference(self.registers.values_list()):
            print("Values changed")

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

> Note that I interact with the models in Django Admin.

When I save the instance, I always get the old values for `self.__class__.objects.get(pk=self.pk).registers.all()` and `self.registers.all()`, and It seems that new values (new selected instances) never come.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing the same issue, I end up using `m2m_changed` signal ([Documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#m2m-changed)). This signal triggers for any change in a many to many field....

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=A.registers.through)
def function_to(sender, instance, model, pk_set, action, **kwargs):
    ''' '''
    if action == 'post_add':
        pass
```